# Python selenium webdriver tests causing "serious error" when run in large batches on windows XP

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

We run a bunch of Python test scripts on a group of test stations.  The test scripts interface with hardware units on these test stations, so we're stuck running one test script at a time per station (we can't virtualize everything).  We built a tool to assign tests to different stations and report test results - this allows us to queue up thousands of tests and let these run overnight, or for any length of time.

Occasionally, what we've found is that test stations will drop out of the cluster.  When I remotely log into them, I get a black screen, then they reboot, then upon logging in I'm notified that windows XP had a "serious error".  The Event Log contains a record of this error, which states `Category: (102)` and `Event ID: 1003`.

Previously, we found that this was caused by the creation of hundreds of temporary Firefox profiles - our tests use selenium webdriver to automate website interactions, and each time we started a new browser, a temporary Firefox profile was created.  We added a step in the cleanup between each test that empties these temporary Firefox profiles, but we're still finding that stations drop out sometime, and always with this serious error and record in the Event Log.

I would like to find the root cause of this problem, but I don't know how to go about doing this.  I've tried searching for information about how to read event log entries, but I haven't turned up anything that helps.  I'm open to any suggestions for ways to go about debugging this issue.

Comment: 1003 just means the machine BSODed, at least according to what I've found.  The first parameter is the error code, which should start to help you narrow down what is going on.  Also look for accompanying 1001 events, as the docs suggest that additional relevant info can be found there frequently.

Comment: Thanks.  Okay - I've found the 1001 events, which are save dumps.  I've downloaded, installed and run the dumpchk.exe program which prints out about a page of "32 bit Kernel Mini Dump Analysis" with sections DUMP_HEADER32, TRIAGE_DUMP32, Kernel information, and Unloaded modules.  Unfortunately none of it makes any sense to me.

Comment: Can you post an example dump to pastebin or something?  Also, how exactly was the root cause the temp profiles?  Were you filling the HDD?  Hitting an I/O error or a bad drive sector or something?  Running out of memory?

Comment: Here's an example: http://pastebin.com/dsquKgJf
The theory at the time was that the temp profiles were filling the HD, but that doesn't make sense to me as a reboot would not have deleted these files to my knowledge.  Running out of memory would make more sense, but in that case deleting the temp files wouldn't have fixed the problem.  I wasn't the one who implemented that solution, but I've verified that the solution was to delete the temp internet files.

Comment: Do you have some McAfee suite installed on those machines?  I don't claim to be a Windows expert, but it looks like you are playing some audio from a CD and McAfee is playing guard dog on the data stream.  Try eliminating everything other than the components you absolutely need from the machines.

Comment: Yes, we do have McAfee running.  These lab computers are controlled by IS, sadly, and they push updates to them regularly.  I should've mentioned this right away, but we recently were required to upgrade to Firefox 16.0.1, and have seen these problems happen far more frequently after that.  There's no CD in any of these machines though, and we can't uninstall McAfee, unfortunately.

Comment: @Nathan, can you disable McAfee at least? Currently sounds like this is a software conflict.

Comment: Well, there's your problem; you need to control your own machines.  Talk to IS about establishing a different set of policies for these lab machines.  Machines that are randomly getting updates pushed to them and security scans run on them do not make good automated test slaves.  You are testing a website, not McAfee, so your systems need to be configured as such.

Comment: Hmm, I totally agree, but my 25,000 company is less than likely to approve of that.  I'll still give it a shot, but moreover, McAfee was installed on these machines previously too, and we only started seeing this problem frequently when we switched from Firefox 3.6 to Firefox 16.0.1.

Comment: @Nathan, going from Firefox 3.6 to 16.0.1 was a big jump, why was the machine not updated more frequently?

Comment: @Arran - We have other tests/test teams which do browser compatibility testing.  The automated test suite uses a stable version to develop a toolset, which faces a lengthy validation process (due to our highly regulated industry).  Since the cost of such an update is quite high, we do so only when deemed necessary.

Comment: Why are you using Windows XP? Does it run on later versions of windows?

Comment: @Nathan: Can you try to use WebDriver (Chrome) other than Firefox and check if u are facing the same issue. Please stay away from IE :P

Comment: Are your profiles different? Do you have the option to reuse them?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar problems before with Firefox. The rare times that we managed to catch a machine in the act it was just not closing browser sessions. Hence the BSOD eventually. Obviously this was a bug in either webdriver, firefox, or XP (which we were also using). We solved it by aggressively killing every firefox process between each individual test. This worked for us. And because you are not running tests in parallel it would work for you as well. By agressively I mean putting an axe through it. The windows equivalent of `killall -9 firefox`. Because these sessions were unresponsive.

As to the root cause? The problem did not occur with specific versions of Firefox. But we never actually managed to debug it properly. Debugging was very difficult because it wasn't reproducible under short test runs and once the issue arose it really did cause a hard crash.